# android layouts - using ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I want to create the following layout - 
http://postimg.org/image/56e9y0hrj/

But when I use the Relative layout and write the following code, I get something like this. 
http://postimg.org/image/4gm0r15k1/

Here is mt xml file -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#5c575c"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Top Stories"
    android:background="#ccc6ba"
    style="@style/format"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="160dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:src="@drawable/one" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="160dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/two" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    style="@style/format_text"
    android:background="#ccc6ba"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="A sample widget for multiple lines"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/imageView1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    style="@style/format_text"
    android:background="#ccc6ba"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:text="A sample widget for multiple lines"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
    android:text="World"
    android:background="#ccc6ba"
    style="@style/format"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="160dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:src="@drawable/three" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="160dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/four" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    style="@style/format_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
    android:background="#ccc6ba"
    android:text="A sample widget for multiple lines"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    style="@style/format_text"
    android:background="#ccc6ba"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
    android:text="A sample widget for multiple lines"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    style="@style/format"
    android:background="#ccc6ba"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
    android:text="Cricket"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have gone through http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html and http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/ but could not find the solution. The images I use are of dimention 400by300 generated by http://dummyimage.com/

Please help me out !

Comment: If You are using fixed sizes, You have to do different layout.xml for multiple screen usage. The picture inside the emulator shows, that the imageViews are too big to set completely on screen. This needs a little workaround of your layout.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Can you explain a little bit more how that can be done ? do I need to make a smaller size image ?

Comment: screenshots are just amazing!

Comment: @vhd Post Images here, Other Sites Contains Abusive Content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible layout workaround, just from scratch, should show only my idea and is not testet: Do two LinearLayouts which specify layout_weight="1" inside one parent LinearLayout. This segments both LinearLayouts inside to the same size. Inside these two LinearLayouts, set the imageView and textView. But also, here You have to do different layout.xml for multiple screen usage.

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_weight="1">
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="160dp"
       android:scaleType="center"
       android:src="@drawable/one"
       />
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView2"
       style="@style/format_text"
       android:background="#ccc6ba"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
       android:text="A sample widget for multiple lines"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_weight="1">
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="160dp"
       android:scaleType="center"
       android:src="@drawable/two"
       />
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView3"
       style="@style/format_text"
       android:background="#ccc6ba"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
       android:text="A sample widget for multiple lines""/>
   </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

And then, You have define some new layout folders inside res-folder in your project. You need folders for different sizes. Inside these folder you have to define a layout file where the image views got different heights to match to the related screen size. But this is beyond the frame, so You have to learn a little bit about using multiple screen sizes:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

using Fragments is even possible:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

### EDIT

This behaviour of your textvies is because of the different screen sizes. That´s what I had talking about, to get all looking good, You have to do more than only one layout. Here are some examples how one layout looks on different screens:

HTC Desire S 3.7 inches

[image]

the imageViews and TextViews fill the whole width, so the textViews are completely as width as the imageViews. By default, the textView wraps automatically if the text is too long, but this could be device dependant. Usally define maxLines, that will cause wrap text inside the textView. But if the text is shorter than the width, it doesn´t wrap.

Device with 5.1 inches

[image]

here the text is shorter than the width, so it doesn´t wrap. You could fix this by set fixed sizes to textView.

But this is all just scratches the subject, I can´t complain the whole thing in here. You have to learn how to handle different layouts. You have to set fixed sizes to different layouts, different resources and so on.

Comment: I need to apply different fragments in my app. Can I use linear layout ? or I need to use relative layout ?

Comment: Are the image sizes ok for now which I have defined in drawable folder (400by300) ?

Comment: this depends on what You want. If You just want to look it like the image in that link, it is possible to use LinearLayout, but even RelativeLayout.Or another usage is Fragments... There is no limitation of usage, because of this it will be better to read all about in that link i posted above. The explanation would be too complicated to discuss it here. I set some links in my answer.